# UserScript to Make Textarea Boxes Expandable

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey, userscripts

I regularly use a website with a lot of textarea boxes, but the stupid thing is that they aren't expandable and thus adding a lot of text to them (which I do frequently) feels quite cramped and is more difficult than I would like it to be. I would like to make a greasemonkey script/UserScript or some sort of javascript I can paste in the Chrome Console to change this part of the HTML/CSS:

```
resize: none
```

To:

```
resize: true
```

This makes the textarea box have the little gripper at the bottom and solves the problem

[image: cornergripper]

A few things to note are 1. this website seems to be dynamically generated from some sort of CMS and 2. I don't have the ability to change any content on this CMS. Also, I'm sure there is a better way to ask this question..

Another thing is that all I want is for the textarea to always be big enough to house all of the text, so if there is a way to automatically expand to the text, that'd be great. Also, it'd be great to have the textarea gripper on the stackoverflow new post text box!

[image: bottomgripper]

Full example code is below where you will find 'resize: none'
Many thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" class="content_tab_bg_padding" align="left">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="height2"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="form_label_text" align="left" valign="top">Gotta change this text box to be permanently expandable. Ideally automatically expandable. 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding-top: 2px;">
                        <textarea
                            name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$ctl00$ctl00$TextArea_CustomDocumentNoteGenerals_PersonPresent"
                            id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_ctl00_ctl00_TextArea_CustomDocumentNoteGenerals_PersonPresent"
                            class="form_textareaWithoutWidth element" rows="4" style="width: 95%; resize: none;"
                            spellcheck="True" data-preventexpand="PreventExpand" tabindex="0"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many things are possible in programming, but the first thing to do is to try writing some code first - *then* ask if you get stuck somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example based on your post:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_ctl00_ctl00_TextArea_CustomDocumentNoteGenerals_PersonPresent');

if (textarea) {               // check if found
  textarea.style.resize = 'both';
}
```

**Update on comment**

For more than one `textarea` on the page

```js
document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(item => item.style.resize = 'both');
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up altering this code to the following to apply it to the website instead of the example I included
```
var textarea = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

if (textarea) {  // check if found
    for (let i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
        textarea[i].style.resize = 'both';
    }
}
```

Comment: @LaveyWhiffle Good.. I will update the code for ALL